# Who do I inform when a website is compromised

Tags: phishing, websites

I often receive phishing emails claiming to be big companies like PayPal.

When I check the link I remove anything which could be used to confirm that it was me who clicked and open the link in a virtual machine.

Most of the time the fake sites look to be hosted by small companies. Most likely hacked in some way.

Who should I inform when I think that a site has been compromised?

In the past I have informed the owner and the registrar but never get a response.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing right. If the admin@xx or webmaster@xxx didn't respond, you may check their website and see if there's any official social media, e.g. Twitter and Facebook. To be ethical, use direct message or private message. Sometimes they're more active in social media.

Answer (score 2):

Try to [report it to google](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/). Once the site is blocked by lots of browsers because google added it to their SafeBrowsing checks the site admins will probably finally notice that something is wrong. And it might be more effective against lazy admins which just remove a single affected file and get hacked few hours later again.